# how to solve error when using CMake with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, cmake, caffe

I am new to linux systems, and trying to install Caffe on my Kubuntu 16.04 machine. For that, some instructions have mentioned that I need OpenCV as well, but the problem is, even though I followed all the instructions step by step, I encountered this error.

```
k@k:~/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/build$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..                           
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 54 (504)                                                                                              
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.8", minimum required is "1.2.3")  
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.8")  
-- Found OpenEXR: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so 
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0' 
--   No package 'gtk+-3.0' found 
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0' 
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' found 
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0' 
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' found 
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0' 
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' found 
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' 
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' found 
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' 
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' found 
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10' 
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' found 
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10' 
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' found 
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10' 
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' found 
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' 
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' found 
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' 
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' found 
-- Checking for module 'libv4l1' 
--   No package 'libv4l1' found 
-- Checking for module 'libv4l2' 
--   No package 'libv4l2' found 
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h 
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found 
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h 
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found 
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h 
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found 
-- Checking for module 'libavresample' 
--   No package 'libavresample' found 
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h 
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - found 
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h 
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found 
-- Checking for module 'libgphoto2' 
--   No package 'libgphoto2' found 
CMake Warning at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:56 (message): 
 ICV: Local copy of ICV package has invalid MD5 hash: 
 d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e (expected: 
 808b791a6eac9ed78d32a7666804320e) 
Call Stack (most recent call first): 
 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:110 (_icv_downloader) 
 cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:237 (include) 
 cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:12 (include) 
 CMakeLists.txt:537 (include) 


-- ICV: Downloading ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz... 
-- ICV: Unpacking ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz to /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack... 
-- ICV: Package successfully downloaded 
-- found IPP (ICV version): 9.0.1 [9.0.1] 
-- at: /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx 
-- CUDA detected: 9.2 
-- CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_20,code=sm_20;-gencode;arch=compute_20,code=sm_21;-gencode;arch=compute_30,code=sm_3
0;-gencode;arch=compute_35,code=sm_35;-gencode;arch=compute_30,code=compute_30 
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE)  
-- To enable PlantUML support, set PLANTUML_JAR environment variable or pass -DPLANTUML_JAR=<filepath> option to cmake 
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.12", minimum required is "2.7")  
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found suitable exact version "2.7.12")  
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.5.2", minimum required is "3.4")  
-- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) (Required is exact version "3.5.2") 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
ImportError: No module named 'numpy' 
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH)  
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB
_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN)  
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF - Success 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW - Success 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Success 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION - Success 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE - Success 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ENUM_COMPARE 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ENUM_COMPARE - Success 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE - Success 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS 
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS - Success 
--  
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.1.0 ===================================== 
--   Version control:               unknown 
--  
--   Platform: 
--     Host:                        Linux 4.15.0-34-generic x86_64 
--     CMake:                       3.5.1 
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles 
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make 
--     Configuration:               Release 
--  
--   C/C++: 
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES 
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 5.4.0) 
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=seque
nce-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narr
owing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse
3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG 
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=seque
nce-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narr
owing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse
3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG 
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc 
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=seque
nce-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpoin
ter-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3
-mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG 
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=seque
nce-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpoin
ter-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3
-mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG 
--     Linker flags (Release): 
--     Linker flags (Debug): 
--     Precompiled headers:         YES 
--     Extra dependencies:          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/l
ibtiff.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/
x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libI
lmThread.so gtk-x11-2.0 gdk-x11-2.0 pangocairo-1.0 atk-1.0 cairo gdk_pixbuf-2.0 gio-2.0 pangoft2-1.0 pango-1.0 gobject-2.0 fontconfig
freetype gthread-2.0 glib-2.0 dc1394 avcodec-ffmpeg avformat-ffmpeg avutil-ffmpeg swscale-ffmpeg dl m pthread rt cudart nppc CUDA_np
pi_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND npps cufft -L/usr/local/cuda-9.2/lib64 
--     3rdparty dependencies:       libwebp 
--  
--   OpenCV modules: 
--     To be built:                 cudev core cudaarithm flann imgproc ml video cudabgsegm cudafilters cudaimgproc cudawarping imgco
decs photo shape videoio cudacodec highgui objdetect ts features2d calib3d cudafeatures2d cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudast
ereo stitching superres videostab python2 
--     Disabled:                    world 
--     Disabled by dependency:      - 
--     Unavailable:                 java python3 viz 
--  
--   GUI:  
--     QT:                          NO 
--     GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.24.30) 
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.48.2) 
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO 
--     OpenGL support:              NO 
--     VTK support:                 NO 
--  
--   Media I/O:  
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8) 
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver ) 
--     WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1) 
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.54) 
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.6) 
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1) 
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linu
x-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 2.2.0) 
--     GDAL:                        NO 
--  
--   Video I/O: 
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO 
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.4) 
--     FFMPEG:                      YES 
--       codec:                     YES (ver 56.60.100) 
--       format:                    YES (ver 56.40.101) 
--       util:                      YES (ver 54.31.100) 
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101) 
--       resample:                  NO 
--       gentoo-style:              YES 
--     GStreamer:                   NO 
--     OpenNI:                      NO 
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO 
--     OpenNI2:                     NO 
--     PvAPI:                       NO 
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO 
--     UniCap:                      NO 
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO 
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES 
--     XIMEA:                       NO 
--     Xine:                        NO 
--     gPhoto2:                     NO 
--  
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads 
--  
--   Other third-party libraries: 
--     Use IPP:                     9.0.1 [9.0.1] 
--          at:                     /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx 
--     Use IPP Async:               NO 
--     Use VA:                      NO 
--     Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO 
--     Use Eigen:                   NO 
--     Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 9.2) 
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES 
--     Use custom HAL:              NO 
--  
--   NVIDIA CUDA 
--     Use CUFFT:                   YES 
--     Use CUBLAS:                  NO 
--     USE NVCUVID:                 NO 
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             20 21 30 35 
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:            30 
--     Use fast math:               NO 
--  
--   OpenCL: 
--     Version:                     dynamic 
--     Include path:                /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2 
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO 
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO 
--  
--   Python 2: 
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.12) 
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.12) 
--     numpy:                       /home/k/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.15.1) 
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages 
--  
--   Python 3: 
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2) 
--  
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7 
--  
--   Java: 
--     ant:                         NO 
--     JNI:                         NO 
--     Java wrappers:               NO 
--     Java tests:                  NO 
--  
--   Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled 
--  
--   Documentation: 
--     Doxygen:                     NO 
--     PlantUML:                    NO 
--  
--   Tests and samples: 
--     Tests:                       YES 
--     Performance tests:           YES 
--     C/C++ Examples:              NO 
--  
--   Install path:                  /usr/local 
--  
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/build 
-- ----------------------------------------------------------------- 
--  
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND. 
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files: 
CUDA_nppi_LIBRARY (ADVANCED) 
   linked by target "opencv_cudev" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudev 
   linked by target "opencv_cudev" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudev 
   linked by target "opencv_test_cudev" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudev/test 
   linked by target "opencv_core" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core 
   linked by target "opencv_core" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core 
   linked by target "opencv_test_core" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_core" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_cudaarithm" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudaarithm 
   linked by target "opencv_cudaarithm" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudaarithm 
   linked by target "opencv_cudaarithm" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudaarithm 
   linked by target "opencv_test_cudaarithm" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudaarithm 
   linked by target "opencv_flann" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/flann 
   linked by target "opencv_flann" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/flann 
   linked by target "opencv_test_flann" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/flann 
   linked by target "opencv_imgproc" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc 
   linked by target "opencv_imgproc" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc 
   linked by target "opencv_test_imgproc" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_imgproc" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc 
   linked by target "opencv_ml" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/ml 
   linked by target "opencv_ml" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/ml 
   linked by target "opencv_test_ml" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/ml 
   linked by target "opencv_video" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/video 
   linked by target "opencv_video" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/video 
   linked by target "opencv_test_video" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/video 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_video" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/video 
   linked by target "opencv_cudabgsegm" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudabgsegm 
   linked by target "opencv_cudabgsegm" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudabgsegm 
   linked by target "opencv_test_cudabgsegm" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudabgsegm 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_cudabgsegm" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudabgsegm 
   linked by target "opencv_cudafilters" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudafilters 
   linked by target "opencv_cudafilters" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudafilters 
   linked by target "opencv_test_cudafilters" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudafilters 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_cudafilters" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudafilters 
   linked by target "opencv_cudaimgproc" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudaimgproc 
   linked by target "opencv_cudaimgproc" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudaimgproc 
   linked by target "opencv_test_cudaimgproc" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudaimgproc 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_cudaimgproc" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudaimgproc 
   linked by target "opencv_cudawarping" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudawarping 
   linked by target "opencv_cudawarping" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudawarping 
   linked by target "opencv_test_cudawarping" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudawarping 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_cudawarping" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudawarping 
   linked by target "opencv_test_imgcodecs" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgcodecs 
   linked by target "opencv_imgcodecs" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgcodecs 
   linked by target "opencv_imgcodecs" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgcodecs 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_imgcodecs" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgcodecs 
   linked by target "opencv_test_photo" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/photo 
   linked by target "opencv_photo" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/photo 
   linked by target "opencv_photo" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/photo 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_photo" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/photo 
   linked by target "opencv_shape" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/shape 
   linked by target "opencv_shape" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/shape 
   linked by target "opencv_test_shape" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/shape 
   linked by target "opencv_videoio" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videoio 
   linked by target "opencv_videoio" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videoio 
   linked by target "opencv_test_videoio" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videoio 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_videoio" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videoio 
   linked by target "opencv_test_cudacodec" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudacodec 
   linked by target "opencv_cudacodec" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudacodec 
   linked by target "opencv_cudacodec" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudacodec 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_cudacodec" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudacodec 
   linked by target "opencv_test_highgui" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/highgui 
   linked by target "opencv_highgui" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/highgui 
   linked by target "opencv_highgui" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/highgui 
   linked by target "opencv_objdetect" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/objdetect 
   linked by target "opencv_objdetect" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/objdetect 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_objdetect" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/objdetect 
   linked by target "opencv_test_objdetect" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/objdetect 
   linked by target "opencv_ts" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/ts 
   linked by target "opencv_ts" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/ts 
   linked by target "opencv_features2d" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/features2d 
   linked by target "opencv_features2d" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/features2d 
   linked by target "opencv_test_features2d" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/features2d 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_features2d" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/features2d 
   linked by target "opencv_test_calib3d" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/calib3d 
   linked by target "opencv_calib3d" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/calib3d 
   linked by target "opencv_calib3d" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/calib3d 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_calib3d" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/calib3d 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_cudafeatures2d" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudafeatures2d 
   linked by target "opencv_cudafeatures2d" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudafeatures2d 
   linked by target "opencv_cudafeatures2d" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudafeatures2d 
   linked by target "opencv_test_cudafeatures2d" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudafeatures2d 
   linked by target "opencv_cudalegacy" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudalegacy 
   linked by target "opencv_cudalegacy" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudalegacy 
   linked by target "opencv_test_cudalegacy" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudalegacy 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_cudalegacy" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudalegacy 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_cudaobjdetect" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudaobjdetect 
   linked by target "opencv_cudaobjdetect" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudaobjdetect 
   linked by target "opencv_cudaobjdetect" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudaobjdetect 
   linked by target "opencv_test_cudaobjdetect" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudaobjdetect 
   linked by target "opencv_cudaoptflow" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudaoptflow 
   linked by target "opencv_cudaoptflow" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudaoptflow 
   linked by target "opencv_test_cudaoptflow" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudaoptflow 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_cudaoptflow" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudaoptflow 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_cudastereo" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/c 
   linked by target "opencv_cudastereo" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudast 
   linked by target "opencv_cudastereo" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudast 
   linked by target "opencv_test_cudastereo" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/c 
   linked by target "opencv_test_stitching" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/st 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_stitching" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/st 
   linked by target "opencv_stitching" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/stitchi 
   linked by target "opencv_stitching" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/stitchi 
   linked by target "opencv_superres" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/superres 
   linked by target "opencv_superres" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/superres 
   linked by target "opencv_test_superres" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/sup 
   linked by target "opencv_perf_superres" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/sup 
   linked by target "opencv_videostab" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videost 
   linked by target "opencv_videostab" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videost 
   linked by target "opencv_traincascade" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/apps/trainca 
   linked by target "opencv_createsamples" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/apps/create 
   linked by target "opencv_annotation" in directory /home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/apps/annotatio 

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! 
See also "/home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". 
See also "/home/k/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

If further information is needed, please just let me know!

Comment: "No package" errors seems to be *self-explanatory*. Do you have these packages installed?

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing package:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```